# Redireccionar después de descargar Excel con PHPSpreadSheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Tengo un problema a la hora de descargar un fichero Excel con la `PHPSpreadSheet`. El fichero lo descargar bien, pero mi intención es que cuando se descargue el fichero, me redireccione a otra página y evidentemente no me funciona. ¿Alguna ayuda?

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('../conf/template.xls');
$spreadsheet->getSheet(4);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$worksheet->getCell('C1')->setValue('18/05/2022');
$worksheet->getCell('C2')->setValue('1234');
$worksheet->getCell('C3')->setValue('1234');
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('template_RatingShell.xls');
header("Location: template_RatingShell.xls");
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: No es un comportamiento usual, cuando esperas una descarga es una descarga y punto. No obstante, por darte alguna solución, supongo que tienes un botón o enlace para darle a descargar el Excel. Puedes hacer que se abra en otra pestaña, y añadirle que al ser pulsado redirija a donde quieras la pestaña que ya tenías.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP y como podría poner dentro del `<a>` para que me descargue el archivo y redirija??

Answer (score 0):

```
header();
```

solo funciona antes de escapar algo al navegador, en tu caso es imposible usarlo para redirigir.

lo normal es usar un `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="https://link decarga ARCHIVO" target="_blank">Click para descargar</a>
```

eso hace que el navegador descarge en una nueva ventana o pestaña.

hay otras formas de hacer una redireccion cuando clickean el link, podrias poner un `setTimeout` de javascript para redirecionar despues del click en un cierto tiempo después.

Answer (score 0):

Como te decía en mi comentario, no es un comportamiento usual. Cuando esperas una descarga, es una descarga y punto. No obstante, por darte alguna solución, supongo que tienes un botón o enlace para darle a descargar el Excel. Puedes hacer que se abra en otra pestaña, y añadirle que al ser pulsado redirija a donde quieras la pestaña que ya tenías.

Lo puedes hacer poniéndole `target="_blank"`, y un evento javascript.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<a href="descargar.php" target="_blank" onclick="window.location = 'index.php';">
    Pincha aquí
</a>
```

En ese ejemplo, al pinchar en el enlace te abrirá una pestaña nueva donde cargará `descargar.php`, y en la pestaña en la que estabas redirigirá a `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo estoy haciendo con JQuery y ajax.

Es decir, mandas a llamar el archivo php donde generas el excel y eso bastaría para que lo descargue, luego pones un temporizador que te haga la redirección.

Es más o menos algo así:

```
            request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "generadorexcel.php",
                data: $("#registro").serialize(),
                cache: false
            });
            request.done(function(response) {
                tipo = response.tipo;
                url = "tu-url";
                if (campos == "0") {
                    toastr.warning(response.mensaje);
                } else {
                    if (tipo === "1") {
                        toastr.success(response.mensaje);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            location.href = url
                        }, 3000);
                    } else {
                        toastr.error(response.mensaje);
                    }
                }
            });
```

El toarst y funcion en general estan esperando 2 respuestas = tipo y mensaje; donde tipo es "1" si todo esta bien ó "0" si hubo errores. Esa respuesta tendrías que retornarla desde el archivo generadorexcel.php como un arreglo más o menos así:

```
$jsondata["mensaje"] = "Descarga exitosa";
$jsondata["tipo"] = "1";
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($jsondata);
```